# Linker not recognizing symbols present in library

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I've got an object file which I'm trying to link.  It references symbols defined in a .so file which I created.  My command is (something like)

```
gcc -L$(PWD)/some_dir -lmylibrary -o program program.o
```

where libmylibrary.so is found in `$(PWD)/some_dir`.

program.o was created with

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O3 -c program.c -I$(SOME_DIR)
```

I get a linker error that the following symbols could not be found: `nodeSplitSize`, `yyparse`, `programTree`

However, running

```
nm -gD some_dir/libmylibrary.so
```

yields

```
...
0000000000004d90 T nodeSplitSize
...
0000000000005610 T yyparse
...
000000000021eaa0 B programTree
...
```

If it helps, `nodeSplitSize` and `yyparse` are functions whereas `programTree` is a global, uninitiated variable.

Comment: Try: `gcc -L$(PWD)/some_dir -o program program.o -lmylibrary`